# How do I create a modded firmware for Samsung Galaxy A54?

Tags: samsung, rooting, rom-flashing, device-firmware, frp

I'm dealing with a very lengthy and drawn-out FRP bypass. This Samsung Galaxy A54 (A546V), which is on Android 13, refuses to let me bypass it, and I literally have done everything except for modding the firmware.
If I can mod and root the device, I know I can get in and remove the FRP lock within the CM.

If anyone can point me in the direction of where I will find a way to root, and/or help me mod the phone firmware. I am pretty sure I have exhausted all of the methods and options available to bypass FRP.

Comment: If OEM unlock is not active the phone will refuse to install/run any firmware that is not properly signed by Samsung.

Comment: if i can open the bootloader does that mean that oem unlocking is on? if not is there a way to turn it on while frp locked?

Comment: OEM unlock is a setting you have to enable in developer options while booted into the regular Android OS. On Samsung devices this allows you to install firmwares with a non-matching signature. A fiormware reset resets the OEM unlock, so unless you have already installed a custom ROm, OEM unlock has been reset and is now disabled.